# bim in .bim file stands for in SSAS

Tags: ssas-tabular

I couldn't find the what **bim stands for in .bim file extension in SSAS tabular model**. I did some search on google and SSAS documents, and couldn't find any information?

My concern would look a smaller one, but, I am afraid that when I start working real world, and failed to know what bim stands for in .bim. Could any one please help me find this information.

Thank you for me your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stands for Business Intelligence Model, or Business Intelligence Metadata, I heard both terms used as the name over the years at conferences and in reference literature.